# Extending / overriding extension in Magento

Tags: php, class, magento, magento-1.7

I have an extension installed and I want to use its funcionality from my modules. The postAction in that extension is where all happens. It uses youtube API to retrieve a video information and save it on several tables on the Magento EAV data model.

Already have a functional module that I created to test youtube API functions using just a button and a text box to send some search term. But now I want to do it automatically using the extension funcionalities to make that call and fill in the necessary tables instead of doing everything manually from my code.

So I need (or want? or must?) to setup a call to that postAction or extend or override it. I'm lost here, I'm new to Magento and PHP so I haven´t a clear idea on what to do.

This is the class I want to call:

```
/**
 * Youtube Upload Controller
 */
class AW_Vidtest_YoutubeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
.....
}
```

And inside it the postAction function:

```
/**
 * Get customer video
 */
public function postAction() {
    $data = new Varien_Object($this->getRequest()->getPost());
....
}
```

I have read the information on these links but I'm not clear on what exactly I'm must do. Follow the `Observer` pattern? Maybe just creating a `post` call by myself and somehow adding the `$data` structure so it can be used on the call? Thanks

- [How do I overwrite/extend an abstract class?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18494/)
- [avoiding extension conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729728/magento-best-way-to-avoid-extension-conflicts)
- [block override from two different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311828/magento-block-override-from-two-different-modules)
- [overriding magento bloc in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161954/overriding-a-magento-block-in-multiple-modules-and-how-to-ignore-the-other-ones)

**Edited:**
This is the code I have until now, with suggestions made by @Francesco. The function `printVideoEntry` is called from other function, inside a for each that for now walks the first 3 products on the catalog.

```
<?php
class Dts_Videotestimonials_Model_SearchVideo extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public $search_term;
    private $productModel;

    function printVideoEntry($videoEntry, $_product, $tabs = "")
    {
        # get user data
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
        $userName = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
        $userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();
        $data = array(
            "ProductId" => $_product->getId(),
                        "AuthorEmail" => $userEmail,
                        "AuthorName" => $userName,
                        "VideoLink" => $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl(),
                        "VideoType"  => "link",
                        "Title" => $videoEntry->getVideoTitle(),
                        "Comment" => "this is a comment"
        );
        $actionUrl = Mage::getUrl('vidtest/youtube/post');
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($actionUrl, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the YouTube API extension you are wanting to work with?

Comment: [VideoTestimonials, from aheadWorks](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/video-testimonials.html) I downloaded and it's working without any complain. But what I want is to use its functionalities so I can update products video attribute automatically with new videos, without users intervention.

Comment: Whatabout using an event observer rather than overriding *their* class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to give a clear answer ... the question is not clear because we don't know how the youtube extension works. ( the code is crypted or open ? )

**Call a Controller's Action**

If you want to just call postAction you can use `_redirect($path, $arguments=array())` method. ( defined in `Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php` )

1. `$path` is defined as 'moduleName/controllerName'
2. `$arguments=array()` are defined as couple parameterName => Value.

**Ex.**

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart', array('Pname' => $pValue, ... );
```

This will work only if you call it from a Controller ...

you can find more info about _redirect here: [magento _redirect with parameters that have + or /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538422/magento-redirect-with-parameters-that-have-or)

In case you want to do a redirection from a model or any different file form a Controller one  you will need to call the url in this way :

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl($path, $arguments=array()));
```

so the above ex. becames:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart', array('Pname' => $pValue, ... ));
```

**Observer**

Using an Observer means add a new model to your module ( the observer ) and write inside this class a method that perform an action under certain events, probably you want to calls some model/method of the yt extension.

Then you have to declare this stuff in you config.xml binding you observer method to some event ( any predefined even in Magento that suit you or if you need you should create your own rewriting the magento class ... )

**Example for Observer**

- PackageName/ModuleName/Model/Observer.php

  ```
  class PackageName_ModuleName_Model_Observer {

      public function myActionMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

          // Code ... 
          // just a very indicative example
          $model = Mage::getModel('youtubeExtension/Model....').method();

      }

  }
  ```
- PackageName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml

  ```
  <config>
  ....
  <global>
      <events>
          <EventName>
              <observers>
                  <moduleName_observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>PackageName_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>myActionMethod</method>
                  </moduleName_observer>                         
              </observers>
          </EventName>
      </events>
  </global>
  ....
  ```

Obviously change `EventName` and all fake name according to your package/module/methods names

The most of the difficult is to find the right event that suit you ... 
Everytime you see in magento code something like `Mage::dispatchEvent('EventName', Parameters);`  this is an event.

you can find a list of default Magento event [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events)

I hope it helps you

Comment: Videotestimonials code is open, so I can take a look without problems. I'm once more checking out the [Alan Storm blog about magento overriding](http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override) and see if I can use this approach. Will try and see if you recommendations fits my needs too.

Comment: Hmmm...In one phrase: I want to reuse from my code the postAction on the extension, to avoid repeating code and future bugs when extension code or database tables changes.

Comment: Actions are related to Controller so they are URL ...
If you want to call an action you have to call an url with the redirect method: `$this->_redirect('moduleName/controllerName');`
ex. `$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');`

Comment: the `_redirect` seems to be usefull. How do I fill the data that is passed on the `post` action? On this case the data is the youtube url, title, and name of user (on this case it can be anything as this procedure will be run automatically with a cron job)

Comment: testing...but I have one error, when calling the extension module using the redirect, as I'm on my module it throws an error `Invalid method`. I guess I should add `include` somewhere on my class or modify the config (or other file?) to be able to call the extension from my module, correct? If yes, then can you provide a sample or link where to check it out? I'm going to do a search right now...[found something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161954/overriding-a-magento-block-in-multiple-modules-and-how-to-ignore-the-other-ones?lq=1) maybe this could help?

Comment: Where are you per forming this action ? in a model ? or in a controller ? I have add info on how to use redirect in a model/block file ... find above.

Comment: I'm calling from a controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16244/discussion-between-yaroslav-and-francesco)

Answer (score 1):

Just try to extends your module class

```
class AW_Vidtest_YoutubeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
.....
}
```

example
    class AW1_Vidtest1_YoutubeController1 extends AW_Vidtest_YoutubeController {
    .....
    }

where
 AW1_Vidtest1_YoutubeController1 Aw1 is namespace Vidtest1 is your module name YoutubeController1  is your controller where you want post action to use.

Hope it's work for you

Comment: Seems that finally the solution is somewhere on on the use of the extension of the observer pattern.